# python bottle import a class

Tags: python, class, bottle

Hi I am new to both python and bottle

I have a site

here is the structure

```
|root
 index.py 
     |classes
      session.py
```

from the index.py how do I access session.py

so I can use it as:

```
**from session import session**
```

Or is there a better way (standard) to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make everything under root into a [package](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages).  Its easy.

Place blank `__init__.py` files in the root and classes folders and you will be able to import `session.py` no problem.

The `__init__.py` file defines everything as part of the package and then you can import anything within the package.

Answer (score 0):

Read this instead of the answer below: 
[Import a module from a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/python-import-a-module-from-a-folder)

**Ignore this:**

Depending on what you want all of the following methods are valid. I normally use the first one unless there are a lot of helper functions to use.

`import session` and then call functions by `session.function1()`

or `from session import *` and just call `function1()` naturally.

or even `import session as whateveryouwanthere` and call `whateveryouwanthere.function1()`

Comment: how does the interpreter know where the session class is located?

Comment: This will not work unless you somehow get the `classes` directory into the Python path.

Comment: So does that mean we should put all our classes in the root folder?

Comment: Sorry I misinterpreted the question, read this SO thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/python-import-a-module-from-a-folder